# How to edit a Play 2.0 project using Eclipse

Tags: sbt, playframework-2.0

There is no **eclipsify** action in the new Play 2.0-beta

How does one edit a project in Eclipse ?

Comment: Not yet. Support for IDE integration is coming.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In newer versions on Play the command is `play eclipse`

Answer (score 11):

With the latest version of Play 20, follow these steps:

1. cd to your application folder
2. type `play`
3. run `eclipsify` target
4. import project into eclipse

it's that simple!

Note that it's best to run Play as `play ~ run` when running under Eclipse.

Last point, if you use **ScalaIDE**, step by step instructions can be found at http://scala-ide.org/docs/tutorials/play20scalaide20/index.html

Answer (score 9):

Update: This answer is deprecated.

Edit file `project/plugins.sbt`, add the following:

```
resolvers += Classpaths.typesafeResolver

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbteclipse" % "sbteclipse" % "1.5.0")
```

Open the SBT console:

- cd to the application folder
- run `play`, the SBT prompt should show up
- type `compile` to pre-compile the app
- then `eclipse` to generate the eclipse project files

Open Eclipse:

- Select `File -> Import… -> Existing projects into Workspace`
- Pick your application folder and click **Finish**.

You should see the project files appear in the project explorer.

Now let's resolve the compilation issues:

- Right click on the project, select `Properties` then `Java Build Path`
- In the **Libraries** tab, click `Add Class Folder…`
- Check `target/scala-2.9.1/classes` and `target/scala-2.9.1/classes_managed`
- Back in `Java Build Path` click `Add external JARs…`
- Select `play\repository\local\org.scala-lang\scala-library\2.9.1\jars\scala-library.jar`

Now everything should compile.

PS: [credits](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/play-framework/U44m-kOG3bk)

Comment: The plugins.sbt snippet should have a newline between the two lines.

Comment: In the Scala IDE: `File -> Import ... -> General -> Existing projects into workspace`